# css file is not served in my nodejs application

Tags: css, node.js, express, view

Hello guys I dont understand why my css file is not served when the **url** contains ***parameters***. I want to access a route from another route when I click on the link here :  `<a href="/books/10"> click here</a>` located in `welcome` file.Below is my server config : `app.js`

```
let express     = require("express");
let path        = require("path");
let mongoose    = require("mongoose");
let bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
let exphbs      = require('express-handlebars');
let dotenv = require("dotenv").config();

let app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"public")))
app.set("views","views");
app.set("view engine","hbs");
app.engine("hbs",exphbs({
            extname:"hbs",
            layoutsDir:path.join(__dirname,"views"),
            defaultLayout:"template",
           partialsDir:path.join(__dirname,"views/partials/")
 })) ;

######ROUTING
app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("welcome")   // from which I access "/books/:id" route : css file is served
})
app.get("/books/:id",(req,res)=>{
    let p_id = req.params.id;
    //here css file is not served but if I access without parameter,css file is served so WHY??????
    res.render("bookdetail")
})
```

[image]

**NB : my css file is called `home.css`**

***My template file***  `template.hbs`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
     <title>ziri book</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{{body}}} 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your css file path is relative to a page url. The page urls has different number of levels. /welcome is in root, but /book/123 is one step lower. Solution: use `href="/home.css">` if you host your site under the server root or prefix it with 
{{rootpath}} like `href="{{ rootpath}}/home.css">` where {{ rootpath}} the path to your site root.

Comment: @SergeyL thanks for your response it works with  href=/home.css